# spring boot security prevent the logged in user from seeing the login and registration pages

Tags: java, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf in the interface layer. I want to prohibit login and register pages when user is logged in. Is there any solution to this?

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/persons/**","/animals/**","/animal/**","/person/**")
            .hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/dologin")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/persons")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enforce this, you can enable anonymous access (e.g. required to be anonymous to access this resource). See [Common Built-In Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html#el-common-built-in) for a description of anonymous vs authenticated. You can use something like this:

```java
http.authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) -> authorizeRequests
  .mvcMatchers("/register", "/login").anonymous()
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
)
```

Comment: thanks for helping.  I just added this ->  .mvcMatchers("/register", "/login").anonymous()